# snowflake: if the same warehouse is used for multuple sql commands will it slow down the process

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 10 snowflake sql ie. `copy into ...` which copies data from s3 bucket to table

now i want to run all of the parallelly using the same warehouse

will that affect each  of the sql performance or it will be independent of how many times the same warehouse is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Each warehouse could execute specific number of queries, and once the threshold is exceeded the incoming statements are queued.

[MAX_CONCURRENCY_LEVEL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#max-concurrency-level):

> Specifies the concurrency level for SQL statements (i.e. queries and DML) executed by a warehouse. When the level is reached, the operation performed depends on whether the warehouse is a single-cluster or multi-cluster warehouse:
>
> The actual number of statements executed concurrently by a warehouse might be more or less than the specified level:
>
> - Smaller, more basic statements: More statements might execute concurrently because small statements generally execute on a subset of the available compute resources in a warehouse. This means they only count as a fraction towards the concurrency level.
> - Larger, more complex statements: Fewer statements might execute concurrently.
>
> Default: 8
>
> This value is a default only and can be changed at any time:
>
> Lowering the concurrency level for a warehouse increases the compute resource allocation per statement, which potentially results in faster query performance, particularly for large/complex and multi-statement queries.
>
> Raising the concurrency level for a warehouse decreases the compute resource allocation per statement; however, it does not necessarily limit the total number of concurrent queries that can be executed by the warehouse, nor does it necessarily improve total warehouse performance, which depends on the nature of the queries being executed.